# Given a floating-point arithmetic expression, how to make sure that its rounded result is larger than the true result?

Tags: floating-point, precision, arithmetic-expressions

Suppose I have an arbitrary arithmetic expression where every individual element is a floating-point number (at an arbitrary precision, say, 64-bit). I want to evaluate this expression as accurately as possible, with an important caveat: **the result needs to be *larger* than the true result** (i.e. what the result would have been if all the intermediary steps were computed with infinite precision).

Here is an example: `a+b`. For such a simple expression, we could simply add `a` to `b` using [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) rules, then add a [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place). IEEE rules guarantee that the expression will be rounded to the nearest float, then adding a ULP covers the case where it was implicitly rounded *down*.

Now, how to obtain the same behavior given a more complex floating-point expression, like `((a-b)+c/(d*e+f))/(g-h)`, using only [arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Floating-point_arithmetic_operations) operators? What if we also allow mathematical functions, like `log` or `exp`?

Comment: For single operations you should set the rounding mode to "round up" (many/most IEEE754 hardware supports that). For more complex expressions even calculating anything near the "true result" (as if no rounding happened at the intermediate steps) can be challenging, e.g., if your hardware has no FMA support, try calculating `a*b-c` accurately, if `c` is approximately `a*b`.

Comment: Suppose we had a solution; given some function f(x0, x1, x2,…), we could produce a good upper bound for it. In general, the function will have subexpressions. Where the derivative of the function with respect to a particular subexpression is positive, we would need a good upper bound for the subexpression. Where it is negative, we would need a good lower bound. In general, those derivatives are data dependent, not fixed. This implies we need to be able to calculate both upper and lower bounds. And thus we need [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic).

Comment: @EricPostpischil interval arithmetic sounds like the keyword I didn't know existed and exactly solves my problem. Do you want to transform your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I did not write it as an answer because it is not so much a solution as a whole new set of problems. Interval arithmetic has not proven to be practical in general use, although it might be useful in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

> the result needs to be larger than the true result

A laborious approach would try the equation `y = f(a,b,c,...)` using combinations of `a`, `floating_point_before(a)`<sup>1</sup>, `floating_point_after(a)` with the 3 values of `b`, 3 values of `c`, ...

This makes for `n` parameters 3<sup>n</sup> combinations to exercise.  Code then returns the largest  `y`.

This is not certain to meet "result needs to be larger than the true result" but will be with many equations<sup>2</sup>.

In the general case, this will form a not-too-excessive max `y`, but is not necessarily the smallest `y` larger than the true result.

Of course if the values are near an interesting pole of `f()`, all bets are off.

If `f'(a,b,c...)` is available, perhaps fewer combinations are needed to exercise - again, if `y(a,b,c,...)` is not near a interesting point (local min/max).

---

Even if this does not meet all of OP goals, it is easily enough to code and can serve as a course check of a superior solution.

---

A more formal approach uses interval arithmetic as well suggest by [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418098/given-a-floating-point-arithmetic-expression-how-to-make-sure-that-its-rounded/62442407#comment110405000_62418098).

---

<sup>1</sup> Research [`nextafter()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nextafter)

<sup>2</sup> Troublesome when `y(a,b,c,...)` is near a local max/min.